# Why do I have to utf8_decode() my MySQL column value to get it to display properly?

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, utf8-decode

I'm using CakePHP with App.encoding set to UTF-8, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` present in my `<head>` and my MySQL database set to UTF-8 Unicode Encoding and utf8_general_ci collation. I also have `"encoding"=>"UTF8"` in my database.php connection details.

When I store a '£' symbol in the database table and view it using command line MySQL, the character displays correctly.

If I use CakePHP to fetch the rows from the database table and output them in my website, I see `Â£` instead of my intended `£` symbol.

However if I then use `utf8_decode()` to output my data, it displays correctly.

Is this correct? I have tried using htmlentities() to convert the £ symbol into `&pound;` but it outputs `&Acirc;&pound;` instead! Even when I use the additional parameters for charset.

Perhaps someone can help - I must have missed something here, but I thought that the characters should display correctly (in things like textarea HTML tags) if all your headers, meta tags etc were consistently UTF-8?

Comment: what is the encoding of the field on the database?

Comment: It is showing as utf8_general_ci (utf8) when I run `show full columns in t`

Comment: It could be that closing forward slash at the end of the meta tag, I've had issues with that before. See if removing it solves your issue.

Comment: Tried removing the slash but it still seems the same - the document is XHTML FYI

Comment: Is your character encoding type for your web page UTF-8?

Comment: i am assuming that your database collation is utf-8 of some flavour

Comment: Yep - UTF-8 Unicode Encoding and utf8_general_ci collation and I'm using a TEXT column type in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the data in your database is wrong: the character £ is actually stored as the two characters Â£. You can confirm this by going to the database and using the hex and charset functions:

```
select charset(MyColumn), hex(MyColumn) from MyTable;
```

If the column is encoded in UTF-8, for the value '£' you should see output identical to this:

```
+---------------+-----------+
| utf8          | C2A3      |
+---------------+-----------+
```

If you see anything else, like if the charset column reports latin1 or if hex column reports C382C2A3, the data in the table is wrong. It can be fixed though, but the fix depends on the kind of error the data has. What do you get from `charset` and `hex`?

Comment: Thanks for this insightful reply! Running that query on my table, I get 'utf8' and 'C2A3' though just like your example.

Comment: Then the problem is probably just the browser not showing the page in UTF-8 despite the meta-tag. Is the meta-tag the first thing in <head>? Is the web server sending a Content-Type header that declares a different encoding?

Comment: Thanks Joni - the meta tag is the first thing (aside from white space) under the `<head>` tag. If I inspect the response headers in Chrome, I can see no mention of UTF-8 though. It just says 'Content-Type:text/html'. Could this be the problem?

Comment: OK, so I tried adding `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in my htaccess and now I can see the correct header in the response, but the problem still persists...

Comment: At this point it should be working, so let's check assumptions: 1. How does the database driver encode £ when it is returned PHP? Use the PHP `bin2hex` function to find out; it should return "c2a3". 2. Check that the browser is using utf-8 to show the page. Usually character encoding options are found in the "View" menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use htmlentities with third parameters to safely encode UTF-8 :

```
htmlentities("£", ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work. For example, `htmlentities($myVarFromMySQL, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')` gives me `&Acirc;&pound;`

Comment: You need to use that when inserting, not when reading (it's probably already too late when reading)

Comment: But won't that mean that the database record would contain `&pound;` instead of `£`?

Comment: Yes, it will. Is that a problem ?

Comment: No, but I guess I'm just confused :) if I `echo '£'` in my CakePHP website it displays fine but if on the next line I `echo $myVarFromMySQL` (which contains a '£' symbol that looks fine over the MySQL command line) it displays as `Â£`. I don't understand what the difference is?

Comment: There's probably a problem when you get the information from MySQL. Doublecheck that your field is using UTF8 collation, and you may query something like `SET NAMES UTF8` right after your mysql connection.

Comment: I wouldn't store &pound; for £ and &egrave; for é because it makes the database difficult to search; most of the time you want E to match also é, ë, ê etc.

Answer (score 0):

If all is in UTF8 remove the `"encoding"=>"UTF8"` in your database.php connection details:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
//mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn); // REMOVED. ;)
mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
```