# string from a mysql request, charset issue

Tags: php, sql, character-encoding

names are stored in mysql with utf8_unicode_ci.
i get the names from the db with a simple sql request and echo them in a table.

`Julián` echoes like `JuliÃ¡n`. Can I run the $name variable through some command to unscramble it, or modify my sql request? it's a simple `SELECT name FROM table` now.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822088/why-do-i-have-to-utf8-decode-my-mysql-column-value-to-get-it-to-display-proper/12822125)

Comment: Have they been saved correctly in the database? Is the connection to your database utf-8? Are you displaying it in utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the db connection string, ensure that you have specified the charset utf-8 in your connection string.
And the html encoding charset should also be specified, such as follow:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thanks, adding the meta tag solved the issue. The html output is now 'Julián', no htmlentities, but it display's ok in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Data addition page, check the encoding of the browser. For example if it's Firefox, 
Menu -> View -> Character Encoding
Should have been auto detected as Unicode (UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

execute this query:

`"set names 'utf8'"` on mysql database

before you execute

`"SELECT name FROM table"`

It should work! :)

Comment: also, do make sure if you are using htmlentities it should be like: htmlentities(name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')